# CollectionViewCell will not display dynamic images

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, swift5

I am creating a flip animation on the screen. On view load the page shows the back of the card fine. all 16 images are showing the back of the card. After clicking the button to flip, I need the CollectionViewCell to show different images (card_1.jpg, card_2.jpg, etc..) but only the first cell displays the image.

```
class CardsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var deck: [Int] = []

@IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!

let cardBackTag: Int = 0
let cardFrontTag: Int = 1

var cardViews: (frontView: UIImageView, backView: UIImageView)?

var imgViewFront: UIImageView!
var imgViewBack: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.imgViewFront = self.createCardViewWithImage(imageName: "card_1", tag: self.cardFrontTag)
    self.imgViewBack = self.createCardViewWithImage(imageName: "back-card", tag: self.cardBackTag)
    self.cardViews = (frontView: self.imgViewFront, backView: self.imgViewBack)
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.imgViewFront)
}

private func createCardViewWithImage(imageName: String, tag: Int) -> UIImageView {
    let newCardImageView = UIImageView(frame: self.frame)
    newCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    newCardImageView.tag = tag
    newCardImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    newCardImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return newCardImageView
}

func flipCardAnimation(indexPath: Int) {

    if (self.imgViewBack.superview != nil) {

        // front card
        self.numberLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        self.numberLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        self.numberLabel.clipsToBounds = true
        self.numberLabel.text = "\(self.deck[indexPath])"
        self.numberLabel.isHidden = false

        self.cardViews!.frontView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.imgViewFront = self.createCardViewWithImage(imageName: "card_\(self.deck[indexPath])", tag: self.cardFrontTag)
        self.cardViews = (frontView: self.imgViewFront, backView: self.imgViewBack)


    } else {
        // back card
        self.deck = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 16)
        self.numberLabel.isHidden = true

        self.cardViews = (frontView: self.imgViewBack, backView: self.imgViewFront)
    }

    let transitionOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft
    UIView.transition(with: self.contentView, duration: 0.5, options: transitionOptions, animations: {

        self.cardViews!.backView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.cardViews!.frontView)

        }, completion: {finished in

    })
}
}
```

I followed this articles example to create the animation. https://medium.com/@lawrey/creating-a-flip-card-animation-with-uicollectionviewcell-swift-3-0-98bc96317fee

In my code above I have a label which displays the number at the indexPath inside the **deck** array. but not the image can someone tell me how to display all image dynamically? or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So after spending a whole day yesterday I figured it's time to change my approach. I decided to create two images in the storyboard instead. Here is my final working code. This load all 16 cards with the back of the card photo and when a button is clicked the flip animation flips to random 16 card.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import ProgressHUD

class CardsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var deck: [Int] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgViewBack: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgViewFront: UIImageView!

    var cardBack: Bool = true

    func flipCardAnimation(indexPath: Int) {

        numberLabel.isHidden = true

        let transitionOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft
        UIView.transition(with: self.contentView, duration: 0.5, options: transitionOptions, animations: {

            if self.cardBack == true {

                self.deck = [Int](repeating: 0, count: NUMBER_OF_CARDS_IN_DECK)
                self.imgViewBack.isHidden = false
                self.imgViewFront.isHidden = true

            } else {

                self.numberLabel.isHidden = false
                self.imgViewBack.isHidden = true
                self.imgViewFront.isHidden = false
            }

            if (self.cardBack != true) {
                // front card
                self.numberLabel.text = "\(self.deck[indexPath])"
                self.numberLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
                self.numberLabel.backgroundColor = .red
                self.numberLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 
                self.numberLabel.layer.frame.width/2
                self.numberLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true

                self.imgViewFront.image = UIImage(named: "card_\(self.deck[indexPath])")
                self.imgViewFront.tag = self.deck[indexPath]
                self.imgViewFront.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                self.imgViewFront.clipsToBounds = true
                self.imgViewFront.layer.cornerRadius = 12

            } else {
                // back card
                print(self.deck)
                self.numberLabel.text?.removeAll()
                self.imgViewBack.image = UIImage(named: "back-card-1")
                self.imgViewBack.tag = 1
                self.imgViewBack.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                self.imgViewBack.clipsToBounds = true
            }

            }, completion: {finished in

                if self.cardBack == true {
                    self.cardBack = false
                } else {
                    self.cardBack = true
                }
        })
    }
}
```